# Not able to define BelongsToMany relationship using same models with different type

Tags: laravel-nova

I have Model Organization and User. There can be a buyer account manager and a seller account manager for an organization.

In organization the relationship is like :

```
public function managers() {
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'organization_account_managers')->using('App\Model\Organization\OrganizationAccountManager')->withPivot(['account_manager_type']);
```

}

In User the relationship is defined as:

```
public function accounts() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class, 'organization_account_managers')
    ->using('App\Model\Organization\OrganizationAccountManager')
    ->withPivot(['account_manager_type']);
}
```

When attaching in Nova, have defined on Organization as:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Account Managers','managers', 'App\Nova\User')
->fields(function () {
    return [
        Select::make('Type','account_manager_type')
                ->options(AppOrganization::$account_manager_types)
                ->rules('required')
                ->displayUsingLabels()->sortable(),
   ];
})
```

The table structure is:

```
Schema::create('organization_account_managers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('organization_id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->tinyInteger('account_manager_type');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Problem statement:
A user can be both buyer account manager and seller account manager. But when i try to attach so, NOva gives me an error: This users is already attached.

Appreciate any idea on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version [v3.23.0](https://nova.laravel.com/releases/3.23.0) Laravel Nova [allows duplicate relations](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/relationships.html#allowing-duplicate-relations).

```
BelongsToMany::make('Account Managers', 'managers', 'App\Nova\User')
    ->fields(function () {
        ...
    })
    ->allowDuplicateRelations()
```

If you are using previous version you can try [this](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1585#issuecomment-561972097) workaround.